# gitlab-ci.yml: jobs dependencies

Tags: docker, gitlab-ci

Imagine there are stages:

```
stages:
    - test
    - build
    - deploy
```

And one need to split `test` stage into smaller jobs like `build-test-image`, `pytest`, `run-linters`, etc. Jobs `run-tests`, `run-linters` can be run only when `build-test-image` worked.

I tried this but it's not working:

```
build-test-image:
  stage: test
  image: ${DOCKER_REGISTRY}/docker:stable
  script:
      - docker build -t ${TEST_CONTAINER_REF} --build-arg ENV=test ./backend
  artifacts:
    when: always
  only:
    - merge_requests

pytest:
  stage: test
  image: ${DOCKER_REGISTRY}/docker:stable
  script:
      - docker run --name ${TEST_CONTAINER_REF} -e SECRET_KEY=${TEST_SECRET_KEY} ${TEST_CONTAINER_REF} runtests; exit $?
  after_script:
      - docker rm ${TEST_CONTAINER_REF}
  only:
    - merge_requests
  needs:
    - build-test-image
```

Error:

[image]

Comment: Quoting the [official gitlab-ci quickstart guide](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/quick_start/): `stage describes the sequential execution of jobs. Jobs in a single stage run in parallel as long as there are available runners.` and further: `Use Directed Acyclic Graphs (DAG) keywords to run jobs out of stage order.` Conclusion: either put you jobs in differents stages or use [DAG](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/directed_acyclic_graph/index.html).

Comment: I might actually have missed the core problem above so just to make sure: you should list the stages in the order where they need to be executed. https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/index.html#stages

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In principle, if a job declares a `needs` statement then this job,in order to execute, it has to `wait` for the jobs that were referred in the statement to finish, `even if they are in the same stage`

In your case `run-tests` should wait for the `build-test-image`.

If you are on a self hosted check your Gitlab version

```
https://your.domain.com/help
```

The functionality you need was added in 14.2[image]

Comment: The error is: 
run-tests job: need build-test-image is not defined in prior stages

Comment: This could be related to Gitlab versions. Are you on self hosted?

Comment: Yes, self hosted

Comment: What version is your gitlab? check https://your.domain.com/help 
The feature was added in 14.2,

Comment: Oh, the version is 14.1.1-ee. Well recently update announced in ours. I will wait. Thanks!